# Unable to translate cookie notice

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, cookie-policy

Recently I see the notice down the page about using cookies on this site:

> This site uses cookies to deliver our services and to show you relevant ads and job listings. By using our site, you acknowledge that you have read and understand our Cookie Policy, Privacy Policy, and our Terms of Service. Your use of Stack Overflow’s Products and Services, including the Stack Overflow Network, is subject to these policies and terms.

This text is not available to translate via Transifex. Could this please be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This text message is available on Transifex now (key is `ae7bed3cb192da2aa363ae1b8e4dc4bc`) and already translated at least on Stack Overflow in Russian:

> [image: ruSO cookie]